# Suitable HBase table model

Tags: hbase

I am finding difficulty on modeling HBase table for the following requirement.

I have a table 'Store' where it stores the store details (Pizza Hut).

I have a table 'Order' which has the summary of the transaction (total transaction amount etc...).

I have another table 'Order_Item' where every ordered Item in the transaction is stored (This has the item id, item name, item count, tax etc..)

1. The requirement is, given a time range calculate the total income by a particular order item from a particular Store.

Example : Date Range - Last Week, Store - Pizza A, Item - A, Total Income - 120$

1. The other requirement is, given a time range calculate the percentage of total income by a particular order item from a store.

Example : Date Range - Last Week, Store - Pizza A, Item - A, %Percentage Income - 23%

I am really stuck on how to model the hbase tables and the deadline makes me tensed.

Please can some one assist me on this.

Comment: do you get arbitrary time ranges for query or do you need to show fixed ranges (last 7 days, last 30 days,last year etc.?)

Comment: yes I have arbitrary time ranges. Its like get the last week, last month, last quarter from a selected particular date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HBase, you want to be sure that you design your tables around your typical queries. If you design your tables based on some arbitrary "that makes sense" you are going to see bad performance.

Since the major requirement is to query by date range / store / item, you want this to be your key. If this is your key, then your queries are going to be fast.

I suggest you make your key the concatenation of date range + store + item along with some delimiter, e.g.:

```
20110103-PIZZAHUT-MEATLOVERS
20110103-PIZZAHUT-VEGETABLE
20110104-PIZZAHUT-MEATLOVERS
20110105-DOMINOS-HAWAIIAN
```

Then, store each item sold into the first column family as (ID:profit). ID here is something like a unique timestamp, a UUID, a receipt ID, or something.

For the first query, All you do is do a key lookup on DATE-STORE-ITEM, then sum all of the values you retrieve.

For the second query, do a range scan from `20110107-PIZZAHUT-!` to `20110206-PIZZAHUT-~`. Sum the items you are looking for and all the items you are not also. At the end, calculate the percentage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps me a lot. But I have question.

In the first query say the date range is from 20110103 - 20110105, do I have to make key lookup for every day in the date range ?? Would not this be slow of I have to scan say 5 years date range.

Comment: You are correct; I just assumed they were smaller. In the case of a large date range like that you are probably better off with a MapReduce job over data of this same structure.

Comment: The key suggested has a lot of significant bytes that are identical for a lot of records ("20110103-PIZZAHUT") see section 6.3.1 in rowkey design guidelines http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html

Comment: I restructured the row key to be 20110103-<chain id>-<store id>-<item id> so that now the row keys will be like, 20110103-1-23-333.

When I do a range query using scan for example,
startRow - 20110103-1-23-
endRow - 20110105-1-23-

I am getting rows that are not within the above range as well.
For example i get the row 20110105-1-15-6666 as well.

Please can some one assist me on this.

Comment: Can the above problem solved by using a RegEx filter along with startRow - 20110103 and endRow - 20110105 ??

Comment: If we do a range scan with STARTROW as 20110107-PIZZAHUT-! and  END ROW as 20110206-PIZZAHUT-~ , will we not get 20110107-SOMEOTHERSTORES- as well in the result set , since it is a lexicographical scan and it will fetch all the rows starting from the date(in the first part of the key) , irrespective of the second part of row key i.e.  'PIZZAHUT'?

Answer (score 4):

The approach suggested by orangeoctopus is storing one row per day, per store, per item, with a column for every transaction. That's a good one; the other approach is to store each transaction in its own row, with the same key fields plus the unique ID as part of the key. Then there's a single column in a single column family, for the amount.

```
20110103-PIZZAHUT-MEATLOVERS-857283394
20110103-PIZZAHUT-MEATLOVERS-857283395
20110103-PIZZAHUT-MEATLOVERS-857283396
20110103-PIZZAHUT-VEGETABLE-859238494
20110103-PIZZAHUT-VEGETABLE-859238494
```

etc.

The same logic applies in this design; your queries both scan over a specific date range and get the data they need that way (and, if you want to restrict to a single store, or a store product combo, you can do that). The only difference is that now you're scanning over a bunch of rows, instead of many columns in one row per date/store/item combination.

These are the two key design techniques in HBase: entities as rows, or entities as columns nested within a parent entity row. The advantage to the latter is that all columns within a row can be updated transactionally; the downside is that the code to retrieve it is a little more complicated (and, you pay a slight price for that transactionality if you have high concurrency).

FYI, what you *can't* do efficiently with this row key is a query that doesn't lead with the parts of your row key, in order. So for example, if you wanted sales for pizza hut for all time, you'd have to scan every row in the table on the server side (which is presumably not desirable b/c presumably you have a LOT of data in this table, otherwise you wouldn't be using HBase ... :)

Comment: Good answer! Your FYI is very important.

Comment: Thanks Ian Varley. Can you explain me how can I query the rows of a particular store and item given a date range.

I am aware that the SCAN takes start and end rows but will that work if I give partially.

example 
start row - 20110103-PIZZAHUT-VEGETABLE
start row - 20110105-PIZZAHUT-VEGETABLE

Will this return the rows between date 2011-01-03 and 2011-01-05

Please explain me ??